# How can i check if the function exists in my class

Tags: javascript

i started using Javascript OOP i'm still beginner,
i created a class and i want to know if the deleteQuote function exists in my class ?

This is my Class code

```
class Quote{

deleteQuote(callback){
    $('tr#'+callback.quoteid).hide('slow', function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
}}

var quote = new Quote();
var y = quote.deleteQuote();
console.log(typeof y);
```

Thank you

Comment: `typeof quote.deleteQuote` to check the type. If you add parentheses, you are invoking the function. And `typeof quote.deleteQuote === "function"` to check if the property is a function.

Answer (score 2):

You can you `hasOwnProperty()` on the `prototype` object of `Quote`

```js
class Quote{

  deleteQuote(callback){
    $('tr#'+callback.quoteid).hide('slow', function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
}}

console.log(Quote.prototype.hasOwnProperty('deleteQuote'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use its `typeof` like this:

```js
class Quote {

  deleteQuote(callback) {
    $('tr#' + callback.quoteid).hide('slow', function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
  }
}

var quote = new Quote();
let exists = typeof quote.deleteQuote !== "undefined";
console.log(exists);
```

[typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) returns the variable type of the element you provide. In this case, when it returns `undefined`, it means that the object, method, property, function, etc. of what you are searching, is not defined.

Comment: @AmineBouhaddi Hope it solved your issue. Please read [What to do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) after reading everyone's answer.